# Is there a way of reducing the dims of a tensor(numpy array) that has zeros on multiple axis?

Tags: python, numpy

What is an easy way getting this array of size (112, 112, 6) into (112, 112, 3). Could np.squeeze(image) be used?

Below is the numpy.array with it's current shape.

```
(112, 112, 6)

[[[  0.     0.     0.   683.25 237.5  472.  ]
  [  0.     0.     0.   684.25 230.25 465.  ]
  [  0.     0.     0.   690.   222.25 459.  ]
  ...
  [  0.     0.     0.   146.    56.   209.  ]
  [  0.     0.     0.   155.25  69.25 217.5 ]
  [  0.     0.     0.   156.25  69.75 215.5 ]]

 [[  0.     0.     0.   676.5  227.   460.25]
  [  0.     0.     0.   677.25 219.25 453.75]
  [  0.     0.     0.   682.25 211.25 448.25]
  ...
  [  0.     0.     0.   131.    37.5  190.5 ]
  [  0.     0.     0.   138.75  45.75 194.5 ]
  [  0.     0.     0.   148.5   53.   200.25]]

 ...

 [[  0.     0.     0.   650.   362.25 548.25]
  [  0.     0.     0.   646.75 369.   556.5 ]
  [  0.     0.     0.   575.5  315.75 506.5 ]
  ...
  [  0.     0.     0.   755.   765.   763.  ]
  [  0.     0.     0.   759.25 761.75 765.  ]
  [  0.     0.     0.   765.   758.5  765.  ]]

 [[  0.     0.     0.   654.   362.75 552.75]
  [  0.     0.     0.   638.5  359.5  549.25]
  [  0.     0.     0.   544.   286.5  476.75]
  ...
  [  0.     0.     0.   752.25 765.   763.  ]
  [  0.     0.     0.   758.   761.25 765.  ]
  [  0.     0.     0.   764.75 757.5  765.  ]]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation?

Comment: yes, it does. thought it might be more complicated but turned out simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.squeeze` is used for reducing dimensions, not size of dimensions. That is, if you had a vector of shape `(x, y, z, 1)`, `np.squeeze` would make it of the shape `(x, y, z)`.

In your case, you need to slice the vector. Since you know that the first three values of the last dimension are zeros, you can easily slice them out:

```
output_vector = input_vector[:, :, 3:]
```